# Javascript object compilation algorithm

Tags: javascript, recursion, compilation, javascript-objects, compression

I have a static tree that contains a lot of layered repetition and want to compress it, compiling it into its expanded form at runtime. Take for example this example object:

```
var tree = {
    root: {
        "ba": "ba",
        "ex": {
            "aa": "aa",
            "ab": "ab"
        },
        "ex2": {
            "aa": "aa",
            "ab": "ab"
        }
    }
};
```

It can easily be represented in condensed form as:

```
var components = {
    "#a": {
        "aa": "aa",
        "ab": "ab"
    },
    "#b": {
        "ba": "ba",
        "ex": "#a",
        "ex2": "#a"
    }
};
var tree = {
    root: "#b"
};
```

Where the hash symbol indicates an expandable item. I have a compilation function for expanding this representation:

```
var hashCompile = function (rootNode) {
    this.compile = function (currentNode) {
        if (typeof currentNode === "string" && rootNode.hasOwnProperty(currentNode))
            currentNode = rootNode[currentNode];
        if (typeof currentNode === "object")
            for (var node in currentNode)
                this.compile(currentNode[node]);
    };
    this.compile(rootNode);
}

hashCompile(components);

for(var branch in tree) {
    if(typeof branch === "string" && components.hasOwnProperty(tree[branch]))
        tree[branch] = components[tree[branch]];
}
console.log(tree);
```

However, the line `currentNode = rootNode[currentNode];` doesn't seem to do its job. I'm wondering if anyone has an idea as to how I might fix this?

Comment: The initial post was drawn from multiple places, I've fixed the names so that they work together properly (compileTest -> components) So now copy-pasting the code should show the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
function test(value) {
  value = value + 1; // X
  console.log(value);
}
var a = 1;
test(a); // 2
console.log(a); // 1
var b = {inner: 1};
test(b.inner); // 2
console.log(b.inner); // 1
```

Assignment to an argument doesn't propagate it out to an L-value in the call site.

You might try having the function return a value.

```
function test2(value) {
  return value + 1;
}
var a = 1;
a = test2(a);
var b = {inner: 1};
b.inner = test2(b.inner);
```

Answer (score 0):

I altered my algorithm in part due to guest's observation:

```
var hashCompile = function (rootNode) {
    this.compile = function (currentNode) {
        for(node in currentNode) {
            if(typeof currentNode[node] === "string" && rootNode.hasOwnProperty(currentNode[node])) {
                currentNode[node] = rootNode[currentNode[node]];
                compile(currentNode[node]);
            }
            else if(typeof currentNode === "object")
                compile(currentNode[node]);
        }
    };
    this.compile(rootNode);
};
```